# Logstash @timestamp format change for syslog

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, rsyslog

I am using logstash pipeline to ingest data into rsyslog server .

Currently the **@timestamp** value being added by logstash is in this format:
`Sep 27 10:14:43`

But I want @timestamp to be printed in the format:
`27-09-2022 11:14:43.933`

I am trying to change it via this but this is not working:

```
 filter {
      date {
        match => [ "@timestamp", " DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss" ]
      }
    }
```

How can I change the value of this?

Answer (score 0):

The date filter is used to "parse" the input date, so you need to provide the format of your parsed field

```
 filter {
      date {
        match => [ "@timestamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      }
    }
```

it will then be injected in the `@timestamp`

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html

Comment: I have already tried this .But somehow this does not work